# Сравнение множеств на структуре бинарного дерева

Tags: бинарное-дерево, множества

Интересует вопрос: как можно сравнить два множества, в структуре которых лежат бинарные деревья?
Изначально, идеей было сравнить левое/правое поддерево одного множество с левым/правым поддеревом другого, но тогда мы будем получать false, в случае, если элементы находятся в разных поддеревьях.
Например,
`[[1] - [*]] - 5 - [[*] - [*]]`   и  `[[5] - [*]] - 1 - [[*] - [*]]` -- это одно и тоже множество.
Спасибо!

Comment: Я не уверен, как это реализуется в обычных множествах, но вообще можно просто обойти бинарные деревья DFS-ом и выписать в отдельный массив для каждого из множеств все вершины в порядке возрастания (при правильной реализации бин. дерева, вершины сами установятся в нужно порядке при обходе). Далее вам просто нужно сравнить два полученных массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это [двоичное дерево поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0), реализуйте возможность [центрированного обхода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4) дерева, и обходите деревья параллельно, до первого несовпадения или до того, как в одном из деревьев кончатся элементы.

Пример (Haskell)

```hs
import Data.Foldable (toList)

data Tree a = Nil | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving Show

instance Foldable Tree where
  foldMap _ Nil = mempty
  foldMap f (Node left x right) = foldMap f left <> f x <> foldMap f right

instance Eq a => Eq (Tree a) where
  s1 == s2 = toList s1 == toList s2
```

```hs
GHCi> set1 = Node Nil 1 (Node Nil 2 (Node Nil 3 Nil))
GHCi> set2 = Node (Node Nil 1 Nil) 2 (Node Nil 3 Nil)
GHCi> set1 == set2
True
```